# intersection closure of comparison relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am given a set of $n$ integers $X$ and a set of operations $L=\{\geq,\leq,\neq\}$ over $X$. Consider all binary relations  $\bf{R}\ $ resulted from any combination of $L$.

For example $\geq\cap\neq\ $ and $\geq \cap \leq$ are two possible relations in $\bf R$ . Are there any known properties of $\bf R$ and its size. Is it closed under intersection?

Comment: $R$ is not well defined. What do you mean by "combination of some relations"?

Comment: @Crostul I mean R is the set of all relations resulted from any conjunction over the operations. does this make sense

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well, you have simply
$$R = \{ \neq , \le , \ge, <, >, =, \emptyset\}$$
where $\emptyset = \le \cap \ge \cap \neq$ denotes the empty relation.
As for the other relations, you have $$\begin{matrix}< &=& \le \cap \neq \\ > &=& \ge \cap \neq \\ =&=& \le \cap \ge \end{matrix}$$

Now, it is clear that it is closed under intersection, since it is constructed by intersecting relations.